# Is there a way to use custom CSS with the Customer Portal in a reliable and maintainable way?

Tags: customer-portal, css

On [Salesforce.com's Customer Portal marketing page](http://www.salesforce.com/crm/customer-service-support/customer-self-service-portal/) there is a [video with an example Customer Portal from Dell](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zX7P_6cO6PI).  The portal in the video is obviously using a lot of custom CSS which I know can be included in the header or footer HTML of the Customer Portal.

Is there a guide, preferably published by Salesforce, for overriding the base Customer Portal CSS? Is it safe to assume that if the CSS is overridden that changes to the Customer Portal by Salesforce won't break it?

I'm hoping that there is a reliable and maintainable way to override the CSS since the demo Customer Portal by Salesforce is doing it, but I didn't see anything in the [Customer Portal Implementation Guide](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_customer_portal_implementation_guide.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, they provide some [limited advice](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_styling_salesforce.htm) which you've probably seen :-)

**No**, there are no guarantees they won't turn on a [better UI](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/features/communities.jsp).

**But** the portal does look like dogs' balls, so here are some tips:

1. utilize the JavaScript `UserContext.siteUrlPrefix` in the header document to resolve the correct relative path to the CSS resource like this:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.write(
       "<link " +
           "href='" + UserContext.siteUrlPrefix + "/resource/portalCss'" +
           "rel='stylesheet' " +
           "type='text/css' " +
       "/>"
   );
   </script>
   ```
2. if significant changes are needed, there are a couple of ways to get a clean canvas. A very high specificity CSS reset can be used, or it is possible to dynamically remove the existing stylesheets with JavaScript.

   ```
   [I can email you a portal-specific example of a high specificity reset.]
   ```
3. study the underlying markup to reverse engineer which structures belong to which components (you'll be able to grok pageBlockSections, pageBlockButtons, etc)

   ```
   table#bodyTable td#sidebarCell {
       /* the left bit  */
   }

   table#bodyTable td#bodyCell {
       /* the right bit */
   }

   table#bodyTable td#sidebarCell div.sidebarModule {
       /* narrow home page components  */
   }

   table#bodyTable td#bodyCell div.bPageBlock {
       /* wide home page components and page blocks */
   }
   ```
4. because the customization mechanism is the insertion of a Document (!) in the header, one may prefer using `@import` in the CSS rather than the standard `<link />`s in the Document; this offers future developers 'principle of least astonishment' so they need only modify the CSS resources, not the injected Document
5. like any CSS files, the URLs of the javascript will also differ depending on whether the Portal is bound to a Site or not (and again if one uses [Login As Portal User] from the CRM). Using a script loader will prevent having to change the Document, and from clobbering all paths with `UserContext.siteUrlPrefix`. Here's an example:

   ```
   var
       scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
       source = scripts[scripts.length-1].src.split('?')[0],
       url = source.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')+'/',
       load = function(file) {document.write(
           "<script type='text/javascript' src='" + url + file + "'></script>"
       );}
   ;

   load('jquery.js');
   load('jquery.cookie.js');
   load('tab_home.js');
   load('tab_solutions.js');
   load('tab_cases.js');
   load('tab_ideas.js');
   ```

LaceySnr is right about it being risky if they roll out a new theme.
One runs the same risk when styling any Visualforce. Just consider a fallback strategy in the face of changes to the underlying markup. If the new theme is an improvement, that strategy might be to simply turn off any customizations.

But there are two extremes. At one end, foist the out of the box implementation on customers at the expense of their experience. At the other, attempt to reinvent it all at the expense of not leveraging the platform offering.

It depends on the situation. *"I need a visually acceptable customer portal solution in the next couple days"* versus *"the wireframe says it has to look exactly like this, be 100% future proof and my budget is unlimited"*. There's a Pareto principle middle ground.

Portal is pretty yukky for the guy doing the CSS, but it can be a quick win if you know the gotchas.

[image: portal home]
[image: create case]

Comment: If going down the reinvention route (where the only "portal" aspect is user licensing) maybe bear in mind it will be difficult or impossible to access home page components and the "Recent Items" feed.

Comment: Hi, I don't fully understand the difference between 4 and 1. Why would 4 be less astonishing? 1 seems to be use javascript to insert `<link>` and 4 seems to be use ??? (also javascript?) to insert `@import`? Or is there a way with `@import` to bypass the path issues?

Answer (score 4):

I think the video is using force.com sites and using the authentication via the customer portal .With sites, Visualforce pages can be used to brand the portal and bringing look and feel is simple .To maintain CSS  use static resources with proper folder structures and this should be easier for maintainence .

Also Since User is authenticated with customer portal licence you can identify the user who is logged in and present data specific to the User .

Comment: Thanks Mohith. Are you sure it is using Force.com Sites? It looked to me like the layout was the same as Customer Portal with tabs at the top, search on the sidebar, lists, etc., but just styled differently.  That, and the video said  nothing about Force.com Sites and calls it an "Example portal from Dell".  Maybe they are just using "Portal" in the generic sense in the video narration.

Comment: I am sure there is nothing in the portal that we can rebrand completely the body as you said and bringing tabs above and recent items is not so complex and you need visualforce pages for sure for such nice user experience.

Comment: Some of the URLs in the video are /apex/visualforce_page , would that not be different using force.som sites ?

Comment: @Sdry Please note that they authenticate user using portal .So as i see in video the user is logged in after signing.Now you can surely use /apex/Visualforce .

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from a video but it's generally not a good idea to use CSS to override the default styling on Customer Portal. I've done it myself, and it could well be that the structure never changes, but you're not in control of it and if Salesforce do change it then your client will be in a world of hurt and probably not best pleased with you.

Although using sites with CP authentication means more work on your part in the page generation, the overhead need not be huge and you can ensure that your work is future proofed against changes you're not in control of.